# How to test different format of dates in javascript / jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, date

I am developing a application. In this application have a input field. where the user can input the dates by different formats like

`ddmmyy, ddmmyyyy, dd-mm-yy, mm-dd-yy`

And I need to verify the date whether that valid or not. I can able to validate this way:

`YYYY-MM-DD` using:

`var myDate = new Date("1987-08-06")` // it returns me the date while this valid.

But I can't able to validate with other formats. how can i validate that?

example:

`var myDate = new Date("08-06-1987")`..etc?

I developed my app using  jQuery. I am looking some solution without using a plug-in. since i used no.of plugins already.

thanks in advance!

Comment: Use two inputs for date. One for storage on the server which is *always* in `YYYY-MM-DD` format and hidden. The other is for display to the user which is formatted however the user desires. For converting of user format to data format, use Date.js. I know you said no plugins, but the number of plugins is not a problem, and working with date in JS is a massive pain, so a plugin is really required for this.

Comment: How will you know e.g which date format it is: `01-02-14` ??? dd-mm-yy or mm-dd-yy???

Comment: I keep the configuration and validation according to pages, whether user need to give me `dd-mm-yy` or `mm-dd-yy`. so accordingly i will decide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it with regular expressions. You could define a regexp pattern for each of your formats. Then you can test if the String from the input field matches any of the pattern.
Somthing like this:

```
var regExpDDMMYY = /[0-9]{2}[0-1][0-9][0-9]{2}/g;
var regExpddmmyyyy = ...;
...
...

if (regExpDDMMYY.test(yourInputStringFromDateField)) {
    // handleDateAs DDMMYY
} else if (regExpddmmyyyy .test(yourInputStringFromDateField)) {
    ...
} else {
    throw new YourException();
}
```

You can find an example here:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_regexp.asp

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there's no "parseExact" in native JS, that would also be crossbrowser. So you either need to use Date.js library or write some converter.

For this task i'd recommend you to use "Chain of responsibility" pattern

```
function DateTimeParser() {
   this.parse = function (input) {
      for (var key in Parsers) {
          var result = Parsers[key].parse(input);
          if (result !== null)
             return result;
      }
      return null;
   };
   this.parseExact = function (input, format) {
      var parser = Parsers[format];
      return parser ? parser.parse(input) : null;
   };

   var ConcreteDateTimeParser = function (expression, parser) {
       this.parse = function (input) {
           if (!input.match(expression))
               return null;
           var result = parser(input);
           return isNaN(result.getDate()) ? null : result;
       };
   };

   var Parsers = {
       "dd-mm-yyyy": new ConcreteDateTimeParser(/\d{2}\-\d{2}\-\d{4}/, function (input) {
           var dd = parseInt(input.slice(0, 2)),
               mm = parseInt(input.slice(3, 5)),
               yyyy = parseInt(input.slice(-4));
           return new Date(yyyy, mm, dd);               
       }),
       "ddmmyyyy": new ConcreteDateTimeParser(/\d{8}/, function (input) {
           var dd = parseInt(input.slice(0, 2)),
               mm = parseInt(input.slice(2, 4)),
               yyyy = parseInt(input.slice(-4));
           return new Date(yyyy, mm, dd);
       })
   };
};


var instance = new DateTimeParser();
instance.parse('22122012');
instance.parseExact('22122012', 'ddmmyyyy');
instance.parseExact('22122012', 'dd-mm-yyyy'); // null
```

From this you can extend your Parsers lib with additional parsers. You also can use different sets of parsers by passing them into DateTimeParser as a constructor argument. My code is pretty trivial, for i didn't want to write it mega-deep, just wanted to show the way =)